# Camuflar Sender usando SmtpClient

Tags: c#, email

### Eae galera, beleza?

Estou fazendo um sender de email bem simples, mas me peguei em uma duvida que não consigo solucionar...

Minha primeira ideia era pegar um endereço de email temporário pra usar como sender... Mas depois de algumas pesquisas descobri que é impossível fazer isso... **(Se for possível me deem uma luz por favor)**

Então decidi simplesmente camuflar o email para que o destinatário não consiga ver quem realmente mandou o email.

*Na imagem mostra o email lá do network credentials, queria mascarar esse cara...*

[image: Ali mostra o email lá do network credentials, queria mascarar esse cara...]

Meu código:

```cs
const string EMAIL = "";
        const string PASS = "";
        const string HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";
        const int PORT = 587;

        public static bool sendMail(string mailDestine, string mailDestineDisplay, string mailSend, string mailSendDisplay, string title, string body) {
            SmtpClient client = configureClient();

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            try {
                mail.IsBodyHtml=true;
                mail.Priority=MailPriority.High;

                mail.Sender = new MailAddress(mailSend, mailSendDisplay);
                mail.From = new MailAddress(mailSend, mailSendDisplay);
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailDestine, mailDestineDisplay));
                mail.Subject = title;
                mail.Body = body;
                client.Send(mail);
                Console.WriteLine("SUCESS, MAIL SEND...");
                return true;
            } catch {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR...");
                return false;
            } finally {
                mail.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private static SmtpClient configureClient() {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = HOST;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EMAIL,PASS);
            client.Port = PORT;
            return client;
        }
```

Comment: não perca tempo com isso... cria uma conta no-reply@ ou nao-responder@ e utilize ela...

Comment: Com isso nao cai na caixa de spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só trocar o `From`

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("qualquercoisa@qualquercoisa.com", "Qualquer coisa");
```

Note que é bem provável que tanto o servidor SMTP de saída (o que você usa para enviar o e-mail) quanto o servidor de entrada (o do destinatário) vão tomar medidas para impedir que isso seja usado para enganar o usuário. Portanto, o máximo que você vai conseguir fazer é alterar o nome de exibição.

Comment: Eu troquei no from já, mas... Quando recebi o email, abri e cliquei no displayName (Igual ta na print) e aquele email é o das credentials do stmp...

Comment: @MarccusZavadzki pois foi o que eu disse na resposta. Os servidores devem ter algumas políticas pra não permitir isso. Isso se já não tiver algo na própria implementação da biblioteca de envio.

Comment: Ahh entendi cara, acredito que eu tenha que configurar um STMP local e depois subir ele em algum lugar... Assim acredito que de boa de fazer o que eu preciso, Obrigado!